# PHP Code works well in XAMPP but results an error at my webhost

Tags: php, simplexml, unlink

I have a local XAMPP installation for testing and an webserver for live testing. At my local environment, everything works well. But when I load it up to my server, it gives me the error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /data/web/e36087/html/pdf/index.php on line 11
```

But everything seems correct. What can I do?

PHP-Code:

```
<?php

    setlocale(LC_TIME, 'de_DE.UTF-8');

    $xmldb = "db.xml";

    $xml = simplexml_load_file($xmldb);

    if(isset($_POST["remove"])) {

        unlink($xml->xpath('/data//count['.$_POST["remove"].']/fulldir')[0][0]);

        unlink($xml->xpath('/data//count['.$_POST["remove"].']/pdfdir')[0][0].$xml-       >xpath('/data//count['.$_POST["remove"].']/filename')[0][0]);

        $query = $xml->xpath('/data//count['.$_POST["remove"].']')[0][0];

        unset($query[0][0]);
        //Datei schreiben

        $fopen = fopen($xmldb, "w"); 
        fwrite($fopen, $xml->asXML());
        fclose($fopen);

    }

?>
```

Link to my Webhost: http://livetest.philipgraf.at/

Comment: What's your php version? (local and webhost)?

Comment: It's part of the [PHP error reference](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12769982/367456) on site: [Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22316776/367456) - please use the search before posting a question.

Comment: Oh, excuse me! Altough I searched before I didn't find the Question. I didn't even know that this reference exists!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Function array dereferencing](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php) was first added in PHP 5.4. It's likely that your host is running 5.3.

In short this means that

```
unlink( $xml->xpath('/data//count['.$_POST["remove"].']/fulldir')[0][0] );
```

must be written as this:

```
$path = $xml->xpath('/data//count['.$_POST["remove"].']/fulldir');
unlink( $path[0][0] );
```

So essentially, save your method result to a variable before using indexes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! At my webhost I'm using PHP 5.3 and at local 5.4. I'll accept your answer in ten minutes.